# error on sip install (make) for Python PyQT

Tags: python, python-sip

I would like to develop a Python application with GUI. For that I find a PyQT.
For use PyQT I must install a SIP library.

My reference is : [SIP documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html)

For resume I must do that :

```
python configure.py
make
make install
```

Before I installed the make software tool of GNU and it place into my PATH.

Python configure.py run correctly.

My issue is when I launch make in root directory of unzipped sip tools.

[image]

*(**french** : make[x]: entrant dans le repertoire << C:/dev/sip-4.17>> translate **english** : make[x]: enter into the directory << C:/dev/sip-4.17>> )*

After I click on button 'OK' on error my console tell me that :

```
make[x]: exit the directory << C:/dev/sip-4.17 >>
```

Can you help me to understand why this happen and how resolve this ?

**technical reference :**

- OS : windows 7 pro x64
- python : 2.7.9
- make windows : installed
- SIP : 4.17*

Answer (score -1):

Are you compiling with mingw? If yes, maybe you must say to configure.py what platform you are compiling.

c:\python35\python configure.py --platform win32-g++

Even configure.py run correctly, it can create something incompatible with make.